# AspNetCoreRateLimit Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rate-limiting

Do any of you have implemented the AspNetCoreRateLimit for an API with the Entity Framework Core 2.2 version?

I was trying to do it but it has been giving me an error that it cannot find certain methods or classes. For example:

```
services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitConfiguration, CustomRateLimitConfiguration>();
services.AddInMemoryRateLimiting();
```

NOTE: Those in bold style are missing.

Comment: Are you using this [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCoreRateLimit/)?

Comment: Yes, AspNetCoreRateLimit.

Comment: The `AspNetCoreRateLimit` namespace contains both the `IRateLimitConfiguration` interface and  `AddInMemoryRateLimiting` extensions methods.

Comment: The `CustomRateLimitConfiguration` is an [example derived class](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/wiki/Resolve-Contributors), where base class is the `RateLimitConfiguration`

Comment: What's the version of your Web API project?

Comment: The version is: 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing purpose, I created a Web API application with Entity Framework Core 2.2 version. Here is the configure code in ***Startup.cs***:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList"));
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddMemoryCache();

        // Load in general configuration from appsettings.json
        services.Configure<IpRateLimitOptions>(options => Configuration.GetSection("IpRateLimitingSettings").Bind(options));

        // Inject Counter and Store Rules
        services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitConfiguration, RateLimitConfiguration>();
        services.AddInMemoryRateLimiting();
    }
```

And here is the code for setting the rate limit in ***appsetting.json***:

```
"IpRateLimitingSettings": {
"EnableEndpointRateLimiting": true,
"StackBlockedRequests": false,
"RealIpHeader": "X-Real-IP",
"ClientIdHeader": "X-ClientId",
"HttpStatusCode": 429,
"GeneralRules": [
  {
    "Endpoint": "*",
    "Period": "10s",
    "Limit": 5
  }
]}
```

Here is the package and its version I used:
[image]

Last here is my test result:[image]

You can see from the screenshot, the ratelimiting has been set up.